# Keep widget aligned

Tags: flutter

I'm making dynamic form fields and I want the user to be able to remove a form field that they no longer need. Without any validation errors, the remove_circle icon centers itself in the center of the form field. However, if there's a validation error, it adds to the height of the text field thereby changing the center line to around 3/4 of the way down the field.

How can I make it so that it remains where it is regardless of validation errors?

Code:

```
return Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: TextFieldBlocBuilder(
        textFieldBloc: fieldBloc,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Team name',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
      onPressed: () => formBloc.removeTeamField(index),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Pictures:

What it should look like (even with a validation error):

[image: centered icon beside field without validation errors]

What it looks like with the validation error:

[image: centered icon beside field with a validation error]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing standard comes to my mind but I would place another Text widget below the Textfield and would only display it in the case of error